# How to change kanban process template to agile for msf process template on TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, kanban, tfs-process-template, agile-processes

I want to change kanban proces template to agile for msf template my tfs 2012 server.

how to? way?

may be:
I can create a new team project with agile for msf process template.
a team project > kanban process template
b team project > agile for msf template (create a new team project)

a to b migration(version control, history, work item tracking etc..)

I tried tfs migration tool for migration but does not work. because tfs migration tool can cmmi to agile change.

I found way change kanban process template to agile process template

```
witadmin importwitd UserStory
witadmin importwitd TestCase
witadmin importcategories (agile categories.xml)
witadmin importcommonprocessconfig (agile commonconfiguration.xml)
witadmin importagileprocessconfig (agile agileconfiguration.xml)
```

for report: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/22/update-your-overview-and-progress-reports-to-support-the-portfolio-backlogs.aspx

but how to change card work item type to user story? Other way: how to import card work item type content to user story work item? Or direct way?

Comment: What is the kanban process template?  This is not something that is included as part of TFS.

Comment: Kanban process template is a process template(base agile for msf) for use on team foundation server. Microsoft Kanban 1.0. it is not included as part of TFS.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> I found a way change a kanban process template to an agile process template

```
witadmin importwitd UserStory
witadmin importwitd TestCase
witadmin importcategories (agile categories.xml)
witadmin importcommonprocessconfig (agile commonconfiguration.xml)
witadmin importagileprocessconfig (agile agileconfiguration.xml)
```